# How to backup and restore the system?

Tags: backup

I want to install some drivers for my graphics card. usually when I do that something goes wrong, I then try to fix it, something else goes wrong. I finally end in failure and have a destroyed system and a non working driver.

I want to have something like a checkpoint, or a full system image as backup. something to go back to if I fail. is there any way to do something like this? how to make a backup image and how to restore it if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Timeshift it creates a restore point. It always worked for me.

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install timeshift`